# Use local maven repository in CI

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, github-actions

This is how my project is set up:

- Project 1 contains the main codebase and I have a Github Action for that. This project has Project 2 as dependency in Maven
- Project 2 contains the API of Project 1 (and other projects as well) and is building with a Github Action. This one is installed on the local maven repo so that Project 1 can access it.

Now my issue is that obviously Project 1 doesn't have access to Project 2 during the Github Action. How would I do that? Is it possible to do something like this or do I have to host the project on the Github Maven repo or something?

Comment: You can publish the Project 2 to [GitHub Packages](https://github.com/features/packages) and pull it from there

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam I'll have a look into that

Comment: Sounds like those two project  needed to be build together within a multi module build...

Comment: And what does that mean?